# Vim - Navigate to next differing indent

Tags: vim

Is there a way in Vim in which I could navigate to the next differing indent level?

So from here to there for example:

```
-> var a = 1;
   var b = 2;
   var func = function(){
->     return a + b;
   }
```

Comment: Does this perhaps contain your solution? http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_to_next/previous_line_with_same_indentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for indents made up of spaces (not tabs):

```
call search('^ \{0,'.eval(indent(".")-1).'}\S\|^ \{'.eval(indent(".")+1).',}\S')
```

This is made up of two regular expressions:

- `^ \{0,'.eval(indent(".")-1).'}\S` matches a smaller indent, using the `\{n,m}` construction matching from `n` to `m` of the preceding space.
- `^ \{'.eval(indent(".")+1).',}\S'` matches a larger indent, using the `\{n,}` construction matching at least `n` of the preceding space.

The regexes are sandwiched between `^` and `\S` to apply only to the leading whitespace on the line. Then they are joined by the `\|` ('OR') operator.

Of course the `search()` call could be mapped to a key combination for convenience.

**EDIT**

Chris Johnsen points out that the calls to `eval()` are superfluous, so the command can be reduced to this:

```
call search('^ \{0,'.(indent(".")-1).'}\S\|^ \{'.(indent(".")+1).',}\S')
```

Comment: I think the calls to `eval()` are not needed. They can not really cause a problem in this particular situation (since you are evaluating a number, which just yields the number itself), but they are superfluous.

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen I thought the same, but if I remove the `eval()` calls, it no longer works.

Comment: It works for me (several different builds of Vim 7.3) with and without `eval()`. There is a bug when run on a line without any indentation; maybe you were running into that when testing without `eval`? (The regexp ends up with `\{0,-1}`, which gives E554 because -1 is invalid there.)

Comment: Ah, I was removing the brackets as well. It works fine without `eval`, as you say. I will edit my answer. Thanks!